# Can't get hexcode as color settings on save.js file, although I can on edit.js

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor, color-picker

I created a custom Gutenberg block. Although I use same html structure in both edit.js and save.js, I can get hexcode for text & background color settings properly on edit.js but can't do it on save.js. This "color" value in ScrollTopIcon is hexcode when I select a custom color on the picker and it works fine. But it comes as a string value like "base-2" when I select a theme color on the picker so it doesn't work properly. How should I solve this problem?

Here is my code:

edit.js

```
const blockProps = useBlockProps();
return (
    <>
        <InspectorControls>
            ...
        </InspectorControls>

        <button { ...blockProps }>
            <ScrollTopIcon { ...blockProps.style } />
        </button>
    </>
);
```

save.js

```
export default function save( { attributes } ) {
const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();

return (
    <button
        { ...blockProps }
        { ...attributes }
        type="button"
        id="hco-scroll-btn"
    >
        <ScrollTopIcon { ...blockProps.style } />
    </button>
);
}
```

ScrollTopIcon.js

```
const SvgComponent = ( { width = 48, height = 48, color } ) => {
let pathProps = {};

if ( color ) {
    pathProps.fill = color;
}

return (
    <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width={ width }
        height={ height }
        viewBox="0 0 512 512"
    >
        <path
            { ...pathProps }
            d="...."
        />
    </svg>
);
```

};

Comment: What are the attributes for your block, i.e. the `attributes` object passed to `registerBlockType()`, and what was the HTML output of `<ScrollTopIcon />` coming from your edit and save functions? Can you add them to your post/question?